# Tk basic label placement

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit, ttk

Why, in this really basic code snippet, the data label (lb_data) is not appearing in its parent widget (fr_body), and instead appears in fr_header?

(The heights, widths and reliefs are just there to show the location of the Frame widgets)

```
fr_header=ttk.Frame(root,width=100,height=100,relief=GROOVE).grid(row=0,column=0)
lb_title=ttk.Label(fr_header,text="Title Title Title").grid(row=0,column=0)

fr_body=ttk.Frame(root,width=150,height=150,relief=SUNKEN).grid(row=1,column=0)
lb_data=ttk.Label(fr_body,text="Data").grid(row=0,column=0)
```

Comment: Okay, so I fixed it...

If the .grid parts are on a new line, then it works as expected. Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: Did you read my answer?  I tried to explain it in there ...

Comment: Sorry, I wrote my comment before your answer showed up. Thanks very much for the explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.grid` method returns `None`.  So, `fr_header` is actually being assigned the value `None`.  When you pass that to your label `Tkinter` sees the `None` and assumes you want to make the master widget the root widget (`Tk()`).

I never create a widget and `grid` at the same time as then you lose your easy handle on the widget you just created.  Do it this way instead:

```
fr_header=ttk.Frame(root,width=100,height=100,relief=GROOVE)
fr_header.grid(row=0,column=0)
```